# Cómo puedo importar datos de excel a mysql con node js (usando express y sequelize)?

Tags: javascript, mysql, nodejs, excel, sequelize

Estoy realizando una pagina web para visualizar información de distintos tipos de libros, ya tengo la sección de administrador para agregar nuevos libros y posteriormente eliminarlos, editarlos**(todo esto con Sequelize con Mysql)** o simplemente visualizarlos en la pagina, de esta manera :  [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: Seccion de administrador]

[image: Funcion para traer informacion del formulario en mi vista y crear nuevos libros o registros (la variable Libros seria el modelo de la tabla en Sequelize]

Entonces quiero implementar una funcion en la parte de agregar libros, que me permita hacer una carga masiva o subir varios registros a la vez de un excel con dichos registros, para no tener que agregar 1 por 1. La verdad es que me quede atascado en esta parte y no tengo idea de como hacerlo...

[image: Plantilla de excel de ejemplo]

Comment: Hola, Bienvenid@ al Sitio, veo que eres nuev@ te recomendaría hacer el [**recorrido**](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour), Me parece que a tu POST le falta un Código o Ejemplo Mínimo Reproducible, Puedes leer este Artículo, [**ejemplo mínimo verificable**](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), si deseas tener más información puedes revisar [**Centro de ayuda**](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help).

Comment: Podrías intentar implementar read-excel-file: https://www.npmjs.com/package/read-excel-file, aquí otro link donde explican como hacerlo paso a paso. https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.positronx.io/node-js-upload-excel-in-mysql-database-tutorial/%3famp

Comment: quería saber si pudiste resolver esta duda, ya que ahora estoy haciendo algo parecido y tengo el mismo problema. Gracias